# ERROR: More positional parameters found than defined

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Trying to insert values to a database table through proc sql. my values are macros. In one of the macro it contain a text which has comma in between. So I'm getting below error

> ERROR: More positional parameters found than defined.

```
%let m_msi=123465;
%let m_msg=Hi, Kindly help me to resolve the issue;

insert into my_table
            ( 
Column1,
Column2
)
values
(
%tslit(%sysfunc(strip(&m_msi.))),
%tslit(%sysfunc(strip(&m_msg.)))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the comma in M_MSG is causing the problem.

```
%let m_msg=Hi, Kindly help me to resolve the issue;
```

Try adding %STR or %NRSTR as follows.

```
%let m_msg=%str(Hi, Kindly help me to resolve the issue);
```

You could also try %QSYSFUNC

```
%Qsysfunc(strip(&m_msi.))
```

Comment: it's not working. Can you suggest a different way

Comment: btrim(%sysfunc(compress(%tslit(%sysfunc(strip("&m_msg."))),%str(%")))),
this worked

Comment: Did you try using both %str and %qsysfunc?  It works for me. `%let m_msg=%str(Hi, Kindly help me to resolve the issue); %put %tslit(%qsysfunc(strip(&m_msg.)))  ;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote values when inserting.

```
proc sql;
    create table my_table 
    (
        column1 char(200),
        column2 char(200)
    );
quit;

%let m_msi=123465;
%let m_msg=Hi, Kindly help me to resolve the issue;

proc sql;
    insert into my_table ( 
        Column1,
        Column2
    )
    values (
        "&m_msi",
        "&m_msg"
    );
quit;
```